# How to turn on monitor mode on BCM4360 [14e4:43a0]?

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, aircrack-ng

I have been trying to turn on monitor mode with no success.

```
   sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 down
   sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 mode monitor
```

this is the error i get:

```
   Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
       SET failed on device wlp2s0 ; Operation not supported.
```

Does this mean my wireless card simply does not support monitor mode? If so what are my options here?

I read somewhere that the wl driver doesn't support monitor mode so i did:

```
    sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

but I had no success. Whenever i purge the bcmwl-kernel-source, my internet connection simply stops working, even if i have b43 installed.

Ok so after being shown that there my driver does not support monitor mode and b43 is not supported, I figured out a solution for this problem. Just for reference:

https://pentestmac.wordpress.com/tag/bcm4360/

Although that link is for Kali Linux, it works fine for Ubuntu. When you run the following command:

```
   echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/brcm_monitor0
```

It will let you use prism0 with air0dump.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: If you are using `wl` driver, it does not support monitor.

Comment: do I have any options? @Pilot6

Comment: I don't know. I don't track open source drivers. If there is no open source driver supporting this chip, then you have no options on Linux.

Comment: `b43` doesn't support this adapter, so installing firmware for it won't help. I searched a bit and I am fraid there is no dice with this adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: This adapter doesn't support monitor mode on Linux.

Broadcom proprietary drivers never supported this mode, and there is no open source driver for this device yet.